# I'm a little confused with strings and integers, and I keep getting this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("You may invite up to six people to your party.")
name = input("Enter invitee's name (or just press enter to finish): ")
nameList = ["","","","","",""]
currentName = 0

while name != "":
    if currentName > 5:
        break #If more than 6 names are input, while loop ends.
    else:
        nameList[currentName] = name
        name = input("Enter invitee's name (or just press enter to finish): ")
        currentName = currentName + 1

for i in len(nameList):
    invitee = nameList[i]

    print(invitee + ", please attend our party this Saturday!")
```

Answer (score 2):

The only syntactic problem with your code is that you can't do `for i in len(nameList)`, you have to use `range()` if you want to loop a certain number of times. It will work if you change the last section to:

```
for i in range(len(nameList)): # range(5) makes a list like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    invitee = nameList[i]

    print(invitee + ", please attend our party this Saturday!")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! As you can tell, I'm super new at this.

Answer (score 2):

`len(nameList)` returns an integer you should call `range(len(nameList))` instead. However, the code will be cleaner if you write it like:

```
print("You may invite up to six people to your party.")

name_list = []
for current_name in range(6):
    name = input("Enter invitee's name (or just press enter to finish): ")
    if not name:
        break
    name_list.append(name)

for invitee in name_list:
    print(invitee + ", please attend our party this Saturday!")
```